# Is there a nicer way to implement Display for structs that own collections of things with DIsplay?

Tags: rust

I keep finding myself writing `Display` for structs that hold `Vec` of some type that implements `Display`. For example:

```
use std::fmt::Display;
struct VarTerm {
    pub coeffecient: usize,
    pub var_name: String,
}
impl Display for VarTerm {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}{}", self.coeffecient, self.var_name)
    }
}
struct Function {
    pub terms: Vec<VarTerm>,
}
impl Display for Function {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let strings = self
            .terms
            .iter()
            .map(|s| format!("{}", s))
            .collect::<Vec<String>>()
            .join(" + ");
        write!(f, "{}", strings)
    }
}
fn main() {
    let my_function = Function {
        terms: vec![
            VarTerm {coeffecient: 2,var_name: "x".to_string(),},
            VarTerm {coeffecient: 4,var_name: "y".to_string(),},
            VarTerm {coeffecient: 5,var_name: "z".to_string(),},
        ],
    };
    println!("All that work to print something: {}", my_function)
}
```

This looks bulky and ugly to me in a bunch of places - coming from higher-level languages I'm never a fan of the `.iter()/.collect()` sandwiching (I kind of get why it's needed but it's annoying when 90+ percent of the time I'm just going from `Vec` to `Vec`). In this case it's also compounded by the `format!()` call, which I swear has to be the wrong way to do that.

I'm not sure how much of this is inherent to Rust and how much is me not knowing the right way. I want to get as close as possible to something like:

`self.terms.map(toString).join(" + ")`, which is about what I'd expect in something like Scala.

How close can I get to there? Along the way, is there anything to be done about the aforementioned `iter`/`collect` sandwiching in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an eerie coincidence, literally 2 minutes ago I looked at a few methods in the `itertools` crate. How about this one:

https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.join

```
fn join(&mut self, sep: &str) -> String
where
    Self::Item: Display
```

> Combine all iterator elements into one String, separated by sep.
>
> Use the Display implementation of each element.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

assert_eq!(["a", "b", "c"].iter().join(", "), "a, b, c");
assert_eq!([1, 2, 3].iter().join(", "), "1, 2, 3");
```

EDIT: Additionally, whenever you ask yourself if there was a nicer way to implement a particular trait, *especially* when the implementation would be somewhat recursive, you should look if there's a `derive` macro for that trait. Turns out there is, albeit in a separate crate:

https://jeltef.github.io/derive_more/derive_more/display.html

Example:

```rust
#[derive(Display)]
#[display(fmt = "({}, {})", x, y)]
struct Point2D {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}
```

Comment: What's the process for finding such crates?

Comment: I did a google search for `rust display derive`

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself repeating this a lot you might want to move the `.into_iter()`/`.collect()` into a specific trait at the cost of generality and composability.
You can also pass `ToString::to_string` to `map`.

```rust
impl Display for Function {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let strings = self.terms.map(ToString::to_string).join(" + ");
        f.write_str(&strings)
    }
}
trait VecMap<'a, T: 'a, U>: IntoIterator<Item = T> {
    fn map(self, f: impl FnMut(T) -> U) -> Vec<U>;
}
impl<'a, T: 'a, U> VecMap<'a, &'a T, U> for &'a Vec<T> {
    fn map(self, f: impl FnMut(&'a T) -> U) -> Vec<U> {
        self.into_iter().map(f).collect()
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this isn't a standard thing? I can't be the only one used to mapping `Vec` to `Vec`...

Comment: Because it composes badly (all the intermediate `Vec`s) and isn't very general. It also only saves at max 2 lines of code if any.

Comment: I feel like that's two lines of code in a lot of places... I guess I'm just surprised there isn't some sort of syntactic sugar, to make chains of iter operations that ultimately go from `Vec` to `Vec` (or most collections to themselves) skip the boilerplate

Comment: Just mapping isn't that common in my experience, also `.iter`/`iter_mut`/`into_iter` * `map`/`filter`/`filter_map`/... would make for many many more functions that just aren't really needed.

Comment: Maybe it's just that I'm coming from scala and those monad-y operations feel like half the code I write. Thanks for the insight!